# Determinant of a Matrix Proof: $\;\det(qA) = q^n(\det A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am required to show that:
$\det(qA) = q^n(\det A)$, where $A$ is a real $n\times n$ Matrix, and $q$ is a constant

I believe that this claim is true after doing few examples. However, but I do not know how to start the proof.

Comment: What is your definition of the determinant of a matrix?

Comment: Hint: Determinant is multilinear map. A linear map follows $T(c \bar v)=cT(\bar v)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andrea Mori's method is the canonical one, but I'll add one more.

If you know that $\det(BA) = \det(B)\det(A)$, then you can set $B=qI$, so that:
$$\det(qA)=\det(qIA)=\det(qI)\det(A)$$
Now, what is $\det(qI)$?

Comment: very nice argument.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Use the definition
$$
\det(a_{ij})=\sum_{\pi}s(\pi)a_{1,\pi(1)}\cdots a_{n,\pi(n)}
$$
where the sum is extended to all permutations of the set $\{1,...,n\}$ and $s(\pi)=\pm1$ is the sign of the permutation $\pi$.

What happens if every $a_{ij}$ is replaced by $qa_{ij}$?

Comment: For the record, there are undergraduate linear algebra texts that don’t even mention this property of the determinant. That’s why I asked what definition the OP is using.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott : That's the first definition of determinant I saw (in high school, self-taught ...)

Comment: I think *any* undergraduate linear algebra text **should** (at least also) have this definition of determinant of a square matrix, even if it is given before group theory is completely covered. It's a nice way to introduce permutations and stuff. BTW, this is also the very first definition I learned in undergraduate school.

Comment: @DonAntonio: A majority of students in a typical U.S. sophomore linear algebra class are not math majors and will probably *never* encounter any group theory. On the whole I think that in most such courses the determinant is most usefully and understandably defined as a function on the the columns of a matrix or in terms of elementary row operations.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott , I meant lin. algebra text *for mathematics* . Unless otherwise requested/assumed, I usually write here for mathematics students. In this case the OP didn't even bother to address the question "what's your definition of determinant", so...

Comment: @DonAntonio: But there are lots of mathematics students, meaning students in mathematics classes, who are not mathematics majors. Pretty much all science majors, take calculus, and most take differential equations, linear algebra, or both. Computer science majors typically take discrete math. And at many schools the math majors study these subjects in the same classes, using the same books. (This is all in a U.S. context, of course; but we get a lot of questions from U.S. students.)

Comment: I know that, @BrianM.Scott...and my heart bleeds for those not studying mathematics. One could then expect, *at least*, for an answer when the OP is asked about something unclear in his post: I can try to give an answer according to the level/definition used.

Comment: I understand that there are many students taking Linear Algebra undergraduate courses while not being math majors. Yet I do not understand the reference to group theory: the theory of permutations, including the decomposition of any permutation as a product of a number of transpositions of well-defined parity, does not require group theory to be explained/understood and can be of some usefulness even to non-math majors. In fact I think that a student should not be introduced to formal group theory before s/he is well acquainted with permutations and matrices.